# Spring data MongoDB Criteria for regex search in array

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to search the documents that have specific values in an array field, using MongoOperations.
The documents look like this:

```
{countries: ["UK", "US", "JP"]}
{countries: ["UK"]}
```

The query that I want to execute looks like this (it works ok when I run it from the cloud mongo ui):

```
{
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "uk", $options: 'i'}},  
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "Us", $options: 'i'}}
}
```

The intent is to return the documents that have all the countries that are specified in the query, and to do the search case insensitive.
So this query should return only the first document, because it contains both UK and US.

Note that the list of countries to search for (uk and us in this example) is received as a parameter, so I don't know in advanced how many countries will be in the list.
This is why I was thinking to use Criteria api, but can't manage to create this query using this api.

Is there a way to do this?

Node: I managed to make it work using collations, (see solution below) but I wanted to avoid this, because I don't want to hardcode the locale.
Code that works with collations:

```
Criteria.where("countries")
.all(countriesList);
.collation(Collation.of(Locale.US).strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.secondary()););
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this method for apply in regex in your Query

```
Criteria.where("countries").regex("A"));
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I ended up doing. So instead of this query:
{
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "uk", $options: 'i'}},  
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "Us", $options: 'i'}}
} 

I run this one

{
 countries: { $regex: "uk|Us", $options: 'i'}
}

The second one can be build as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is that instead of this query:

```
{
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "uk", $options: 'i'}},  
countries: { $elemMatch: {$regex: "Us", $options: 'i'}}
}
```

I run this one

```
{
    countries: { $regex: "uk|Us", $options: 'i'}
}
```

The second one can be build sipmly like this:

```
Criteria.where(key).regex(regex, "i");
```

The two are not perfectly identical. The first one does an AND but the second one does and OR between the conditions. For my scenario this is fine.